# Android - developing UI for 40" tv with 1920*1080, will work on 47" tv with same resolution

Tags: android, user-interface, tablet, screen-resolution

I have to develop an android application for 47" tv with the resolution of 1920*1080. But I don't have the real-time exact size(47") device to check during the development.

Now I only have 40" tv with the resolution of 1920*1080.

**I have few clarifications:**

1) If I develop(design) the UI for 40" tv, will this work on 47" tv with the same resolution of 1920*1080.

2) Can anybody explain how resolution differs with inch(size)?

3) How to design for both the screen sizes - 40" and 47"?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, Reason is due to the second answer.

2) Resolution is independent of screen size. Screen size changes the screen density (Pixels per inch)
1920x1080 47" TV will be having approximately 47 PPI
1920x1080 40" TV will be having approximately 55 PPI
Similarly a 1920x1080 5.5" phone may have 400 PPI

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I design the layout for 5" with 1920*1080 resolution, will this work in 47" screen with same resoltion?

Comment: It will work, but you might want to specify dimensions specifically for TV and phones to get better experience for the users. Use Smallest-width qualifiers (eg: sw-300dp, sw-480dp etc)  dimens specified with sw-300dp will be for phones and sw-480dp for phablets and so on. Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html